# vuejs mounted: Cannot set the value of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to run the following function upon mounted but I get an error the

> "Cannot set the property 'days' of undefined"

Following is my code

```
 function getDays(date) {
        this.days = (new Date()).getTime() / (1000 * 24 * 60 * 60);
        return parseInt(this.days) - this.START_DAYS;
  }
```

It is not helpful to tell which line is it. One of the reasons I did `this.days` is that VueJS had a problem for using `let days`

I am not much familiar with VueJS and how it accesses variable.

Comment: We're gonna need a reproducible example. Btw your date argument is never used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your `getDays` function in `methods`, then you can call it in `mounted`

I don't know why did you use `date` arg in `getDays`, but it wasn't used it in `getDays` method

```js
...
data() {
  return {
    days: ''
    START_DAYS: ''
  }
}
methods: {
  getDays(date) {
    // 'date' is never used here ?
    this.days = (new Date()).getTime() / (1000 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    return parseInt(this.days) - this.START_DAYS;
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.getDays()
}
...
```

Comment: "I don't know why did you use date arg in getDays, but it wasn't used it in getDays method" - yea I stripped out many bits to pin point what was going wrong. I suppose when a method get mounted, we pass `{{getDays}}} and not the parans as mounted run the function?

Comment: Yes, but `date` value is never used in `getDays` method ? Updated answer, check again

Answer (score 2):

Did you declare your method this way? :

```
methods: {
    getDays(date) {
      this.days = new Date().getTime() / (1000 * 24 * 60 * 60);
      return parseInt(this.days) - this.START_DAYS;
    }
  },
```

Also, to call the method in mounted, use: `this.getDays()`

Check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-brattain-reziq) for clarification